# Position of hyperlinked text after scaling in a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref

I am using the scale option of a node inside of a tikzpicture in which a text with \href{}{} is hyperlinked. The hyperlinks are shown for the unscaled version of the text. This means they are at the wrong positions. How can I circumvent this problem (or what did I do wrong)? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[scale=.2,text width=1cm] {\href{https://www.google.de}{test test test est set}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it an option to use `font=\tiny` or similar rather than `scale`? Generally, it is considered bad to scale text rather than using one of the standard sizes and it solves the hyperlink problem.

Comment: You *could* do `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\href{https://www.google.de}{%
 \scalebox{0.2}{\begin{minipage}{1cm}test test test est set\end{minipage}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` but I agree with @cfr that this is perhaps not good typography.

Comment: I use `[align=center]` instead of `[text width=1cm]`, and it seems to be better!

Comment: @cfr I want to use very small fonts in my current setting, so `font=\tiny` and even `\fontsize{1}{2}` is even too large

Comment: @BlackMild but your suggestion removes the limited width then which is undesired. If you insist, I can extend the question in that direction and add it as a requirement.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat your suggestion removes line breaking as well (see my comment above).

Comment: I didn't know which borders you want. You could do `\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node {\scalebox{0.2}{\begin{minipage}{1cm}\href{https://www.google.de}{test test test
est set}\end{minipage}}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}`, same reservations as above.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat oh, yes, this solves my issue. If you add it as an answer, I will mark it then solved. Great!

Comment: What is the point in using text that small?

Comment: I am having a macro for pictures in slides and have above of the picture (very small) the source and copyright. As this is not important for presenting slides but for legal reasons I wanted to have it but very small. Of course one could have all the licensing stuff in the backmatter of the slides but I like to have it where the picture is. I hope that this is a justified decision in having very small text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go is to use `\scalebox`, which is part of `graphicx` that gets autoloaded by `tikz`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node {\scalebox{0.2}{\begin{minipage}{1cm}\href{https://www.google.de}{test test test
est set}\end{minipage}}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For me, the minipage was the crux.